# Parse error my PHP file isn't complying

Tags: php

I'm getting this strange error all the time, and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've been watching a dude on YouTube, and I did exactly as his tutorial showed, he didn't get any errors, so I really do not know why PHP doesn't like me.

Anyway, here's the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INCLUDE in /home/a3047131/public_html/core/init.php on line 3

Here's the code:

```
<?php
include "core/inc/conn.php"
include "core/inc/ipban.inc.php"

$ip = '';
check_banned($ip);
?>
```

I've got a folder called "core", and inside of it I got this inc folder, and  there's the two files, everything's right, but I really don't understand this error. Could it be something random like MySQL not being able to connect with my script?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing your semi-colons:

```
include "core/inc/conn.php" <-- HERE
include "core/inc/ipban.inc.php" <-- HERE
```

Comment: Did you mean to make that a wiki?

Comment: Oh my god!
Literally I did not see that!
Thanks man, you're really the best!
Wow, and you gave me the answer within like what, 10seconds?
OMG It works, I'm so stupid, as I mentioned I'm new to PHP, thanks man! You're the best! :)

Comment: @Sam: I think it is thought to be good practice to use CW if one is also voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semicolons `;` after your includes which is generating the `T_ERROR`

```
include "core/inc/conn.php";
                         //^  here
include "core/inc/ipban.inc.php";
                              //^ and here
```

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned above ^ I fixed it! :)
Though, thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it! :)